# Behavior of a holomorphic fuction over annulus

Tags: complex-analysis

I encountered the following problem:

> Define $ D:=\{ z\in\mathbb C,\ 2<|z|<3 \} $. Let $ f $ be a holomorphic function over $ D $ that is continuous over $ \bar{D} $.
>
> (A) Suppose that $ \operatorname{max}_{|z|=2}|f(z)|\le 2 $ and $ \operatorname{max}_{|z|=3}|f(z)|\le 3 $. Prove that $ |f(z)|\le |z| $ on $ 
> D $.
>
> (B) Suppose that $ |f(z)|=|z| $ for $ |z|=2 $ and $ |z|=3 $. Suppose furthermore that $ f(z) $ does not have any zeros in $ D $. Prove that $ f(z)=e^{i\theta}z $ for some constant $ \theta\in [0, 2\pi] $.

I don't know how to start with. To solve (A), it seems that we should use the maximum principle but I cannot relate the module of $ f(z) $ to that of $ z $.

Comment: *Hint:* What can you say about $g(z) = f(z)/z$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply MMP to $g(z)=\frac {f(z)} z$. For part B) apply MMP to $g$ and $\frac 1 g$.